# Problems Importing scipy/sklearn in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, scipy, scikit-learn, importerror

So I've been working on machine learning with Random Forests in Jupyter Notebooks:

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
train, test = train_test_split(MLDF, test_size = 0.2) #split the data 80/20

#No output, but the cell ran fine

model.fit(train[X], train[Y])
predicted= model.predict(test[X])

#Was running, did not finish prior to dropped connection
```

I was letting my RF code run for about 1 hour, and came back. Unfortunately, I had forgotten to stop my computer from falling asleep, which obviously caused the connection to drop.

But when I tried to run it again, sklearn had stopped working. Here's the error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name __check_build
```

When I tried playing around with my first cell, where I did most of my imports, I also got this error:

```
ImportError: No module named version
```

After browsing this site, I gathered that I'm either not running the correct version of scipy or scikit-learn or not importing them properly. So I went to my terminal and made sure everything was updated, which it was ("requirement already satisfied"). My question isn't simply what am I doing wrong, but how does it make sense for sklearn to stop working just because of a dropped connection? Yes, I already tried uninstalling and re-installing scipy. Any feedback as to what I am missing is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Is `sklearn` working in the terminal?

Comment: Apologies, how can you check if sklearn is working in just the terminal, aside from trying to import it?

Comment: That's what I mean, did you try to import it from the terminal in an interactive interpreter session, for example? I'm confused by your report of ("requirement already satisfied") which sounds like something `pip` would say...

Comment: Oh, I should have clarified: all installations have been through my terminal using pip. I have never had to implement some sort of direct path to jupyter notebooks. Should I have done something else? And why didn't that come up earlier?

Comment: No, pip is fine. But have you tried to import `sklearn` outside of Jupyter>?

Comment: Just tried IDLE shell with only line being

Comment: import sklearn and a string to confirm if it ran. The shell ran fine.

Comment: Ok, then this sounds like a problem with Jupyter.

Comment: Other people have encountered `sklearn` import problems, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41292301/unorderable-types-str-int